# List data print in another for loop in Django template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, django-templates

```
{% for i in packages %}
{% endfor %}
```

I used this "for loop" in the Django template, in this loop I need to print another list.

`package_main_prices_list=[340, 180, 170, 95, 500]`

problem is I need to print one data from the "package_main_prices_list" list in one "Packages" loop in the Django template

like this:

```
{% for i in packages %}
[340]    #one data from "package_main_prices_list"
{% endfor %}
```

my views:

```
package_main_prices_list = []

for i in packages:
    package_price = float(i.startup_payment)
    calculated_price = round(max(package_price, package_price * last_price / 28000))
    package_main_prices_list.append(calculated_price)

context = {
    'packages': packages,
    'package_main_prices_list': package_main_prices_list,
}
return render(request, 'pages/shop.html', context)
```

The output will be:

package name
340
date

package name
180
date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom template filter.

Make a `custom_filters.py` file inside a directory called `templatetags` inside one of your app directories. For example, if you have an app called `myapp`, then you should have a directory called `myapp/templatetags/` containing the `custom_filters.py` file.

Then in the `custom_filters.py` file write the following:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

Then in the template, you can use the filter like this:

```html
{% load custom_filters %}

{% for package in packages %}
    package name: {{ package }}
    {% with forloop.counter0 as index %}
        {{ package_main_prices_list|get_item:index }}
    {% endwith %}
    date: {{ some_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Load the custom filters at the top of the file.

Make sure to restart the server after making changes.

Comment: Thanks for replying
I used it but it doesn't work. It does not print any data (blank).
(django 4.1, and python 3.10)

Comment: @Md.AbdulHamid Share your view, how you are passing this list?

Comment: it makes error
Could not parse the remainder: '[forloop.counter0]' from 'package_main_prices_list[forloop.counter0]'

Comment: @Md.AbdulHamid You should use template filter, but I edited the answer with some another approach, try it.

Comment: it prints just the first item "340" for all, leaving the first item. like this,

package name 

date

package name 
340 
date

package name 
340 
date

Comment: @Md.AbdulHamid Try edited answer, I make a custom template filter, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, for your try. your answer works. but there has another way to solve it by "zip" the two lists and then using them. (I accept your answer, but remember that in some django versions, your method does not work)

Comment: @Md.AbdulHamid  I know the idea of using `zip()` but then we need to modify the view also, anyway you got the answer from both approaches :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data in query set. It will be much easier

Comment: can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).